# Aligning center relative to others views

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using only one root layout in my layout file and i cant add any nested layouts. How can I align all my views in center in all screens? For `480x800` the layout is perfect but if i change the emulator, everything is messed up.

Comment: Can you post your layout file: what is the root ViewGroup, and what elements are you attempting to centering? Do you mean vertical/horizontal/both center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want elements within a viewgroup centered, you should use the `gravity` property on that viewgroup.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb1"
        android:text="tb1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb2"
        android:text="tb2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb3"
        android:text="tb3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The `android:gravity` property defines how to align child elements, or the contents of the view.

`android:layout_gravity` on the other hand defines rules which are passed to the *parent*, instructing the parent how to align this element.

A deeper explanation: 
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/